# SQL - How to only show the row with the greatest date value based on ID?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have SQL statements in SQL Server 2008 R2 based on a few joined tables that utilizes all the information I need in my program:

```
SELECT 
  Laptops.Laptop_ID, 
  Laptops.Model_Name, 
  ... 
  Users.Firstname + Users.Lastname AS Name, 
  Loans.Date_Loaned
FROM Users 
  INNER JOIN Loans ON Users.User_ID = Loans.User_ID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN Laptops ON Loans.Laptop_ID = Laptops.Laptop_ID
```

This brings up a table similar to:

```
ID  Model_Name ...   Name    Date_Loaned 
1   ...        ...    Kris   18-08-11   
2   ...        ...    Jo     20-08-11  
2   ...        ...    Bert   18-08-11  
4   ...        ...    Sam    19-08-11
```

What I'm trying to do is where there would be repeated ID, I want to only show the row with the highest date, like this:

```
ID  Model_Name ...   Name    Date_Loaned 
1   ...        ...    Kris   18-08-11   
2   ...        ...    Jo     20-08-11  
4   ...        ...    Sam    19-08-11
```

I'm having problems figuring out how to do this with the SQL statement that I already have. Help!

Comment: Third answer here is probably best technique for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24863984/84206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use windows functions:

```
SELECT * FROM(
              SELECT Laptops.Laptop_ID, 
                     Laptops.Model_Name, 
                     ... 
                     Users.Firstname + Users.Lastname AS Name, 
                     Loans.Date_Loaned,
                     row_number() 
                        over(partition by Laptops.Laptop_ID
                             order by Loans.Date_Loaned desc) rn
              FROM Users 
              INNER JOIN Loans ON Users.User_ID = Loans.User_ID 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN Laptops ON Loans.Laptop_ID = Laptops.Laptop_ID) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Laptops.Laptop_ID, 
Laptops.Model_Name, 
... 
Users.Firstname + Users.Lastname AS Name, 
MAX(Loans.Date_Loaned) AS date
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Loans ON Users.User_ID = Loans.User_ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Laptops ON Loans.Laptop_ID = Laptops.Laptop_ID
GROUP BY Laptops.Laptop_ID, 
Laptops.Model_Name, 
... 
Users.Firstname + Users.Lastname AS Name
```

Comment: I already tried that and I changed my question slightly to address that problem. When I do that it will take the Max Date of only those rows with the same names (user). I need it to only Group By Laptop_ID but it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got your answer, but just wanted to mention you might get better performance selecting from `Laptops` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` your Users/Loans sub query.  It might be a little easier for the next person to decipher since `RIGHT OUT JOIN` is not used very often.  Using aliases also helps eliminate some typing.

```
SELECT 
    l.Laptop_ID,
    l.Model_Name,
    ul.Name,
    ul.Date_Loaned 
FROM 
    Laptops l
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  l.Laptop_ID,
                    u.Firstname + u.Lastname AS Name, 
                    l.Date_Loaned,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.Laptop_ID ORDER BY l.Date_Loaned desc) Rn
            FROM    Loans l
                    JOIN Users u ON l.User_ID = u.User_ID
     ) ul ON l.Laptop_ID = ul.Laptop_ID 
             AND ul.Rn = 1
```